# How to reverse a JSON object?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

I have a function that passes JSON in it's param...

```
{
   "code":0,
   "payload":[
      {
         "time":1349661897,
         "packages":[
            "49381"
         ],
         "ign":"PurpleArrow",
         "price":"15.99",
         "currency":"USD"
      }
}
```

app.js:

```
var Donors = function(api) {

   this.list = api;

   $.each(this.list.payload, function(i, donor) {
     var ign = donor.ign,
       price = donor.price,
       currency = donor.currency;

     if(price !== "-") $('#donors').append('<li>' + ign + ' donated ' + price + currency + '</li>');
   });
}
```

and in index.php:

```
var donors = new Donors(<?php cbProxy(); ?>);
```

And just in-case, the PHP function just gets the json.

```
function cbProxy(){
  $api = 'http://api.buycraft.net/v3?secret=MYSECRETKEY&action=payments';
  $url =  urldecode($api);
  $url = 'http://' . str_replace('http://', '', $url); 
  echo file_get_contents($url);

}
```

I'm trying to figure out how I can reverse the JSON so it the last ign shows first instead of the first one, which is in the JSON here. So how can I re-order the json? Could not find a answer from the previous questions asked and I kept getting .reverse() or .sort() does not work on an object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might've tried to `.reverse()` the entire object. Since you're iterating over the array `this.list.payload`, reverse that array instead:

```
$.each(this.list.payload.reverse(), function(i, donor) {
```

Comment: Ahhh did this using a variable and didn't work. Now it does, thank you!

Comment: Another question, before I make whole new question for this - you might know. Let's say i'd like to only show 5 instead of the whole object. How may I do this? Btw I love Blender as well :)

Comment: @devs: You can slice the array: `this.list.payload.slice(0, 5)`

Comment: @devs: Blender's pretty cool. Although I haven't touched it in about a year, it was fun to play around with. One of the best 3D graphics programs out there, even among the payware stuff.